# Github ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: github

I was trying to open github website on Chrome browser today, but it didn't open and showed  ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error. Except, it did run for a bit in between but hasn't worked since.

I have tried running it on a different browser, but it still isn't working. All my proxy settings (i.e no proxy) are right and all other websites are working. I was working under a proxy before but currently I'm not. The website was working well 2-3 days ago. If someone can explain why it is happening and how to solve this problem, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

**Just hard reset your router! It will 100% fix your problem. I had the same problem.**